# bash script not reading alias in bashrc

Tags: bash, alias

I have created an alias in the .bashrc file:

```
alias java='java -Xmx1200m'
```

This alias works when I run a java command from my shell directly.

However, when the java command is inside a bash script (script.sh), this alias does not get activated. How do I ensure that the aliases in .bashrc file are accepted in a bash script ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alias are not expanded in non-interactive shells.

The only way to make an alias is to source the target script with the one which contains the alias.

```
$ source .bashrc
$ . custom_script.sh
```

Comment: only working method for my mac m1

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
>   `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see The Shopt
>   Builtin).

Saying the following in your script should make it work:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: Not working in FreeBSD/OSX at least. `expand_aliases` is already on by default.

Comment: @AinTohvri You'd need to `source $HOME/.bashrc` in the script.

Comment: Yup, after the `shopt -s expand_aliases`, realised that. Working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are limited to the shell and do not work in executed shell scripts. You are better off creating a variable.

Comment: What about using `export java='java -Xmx1200m'` in `.bashrc`?

Comment: if the shell script is executed outside of the user login i.e. cron it may not get called - he needs to source .bashrc

Comment: @fedorqui Right, but that will not be considered using it as an alias. It is setting a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to do the 2 important things or it wont' work. In your other script, do the following: `-i` for interactive mode, and shopt part as mentioned below.

```
#!/bin/bash -i

# Expand aliases defined in the shell ~/.bashrc
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

After this, your aliases that you have defined in ~/.bashrc they will be available in your shell script (giga.sh or any.sh) and to any function or child shell within such script.

If you don't do that, you'll get an error:

```
your_cool_alias: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script under bash bash in interactive mode; add -i to bash command line, like this script. Now you can use your aliases.

```
#!/bin/bash -i 

alias lsd='ls -al | grep ^d' 

lsd
```